# XMPP sendMessage does not send the message

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using the XMPPservice's sendMessage method
to send a message to google mail but the message
can not be sent without any error log.

Thank

Answer (score 1):

A common error source is that the receiver first has to accept an invite from the sender. Only then messages will be relayed to the receiver. Have you sent an invite and was it accepted?

Comment: YesI have sent an invite and was accepted but when I send a message to the receiver does not reply back and no error log produced APPRECIATE IT

Answer (score 0):

If the Gmail recipient is using **Google Apps** (e.g. Google Apps for Business), the recipient domain must publish [SRV records in their DNS](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=34143) to allow routing of the XMPP packets to the Gmail Chat backend. The vast majority of Google Apps domains will not likely have SRV records configured.

If the recipient is a @gmail.com / @googlemail.com account, then (as *@schuppe* suggest) the most likely cause of this issue is due to the fact that the recipient did not accept the invite from the sender.

Comment: Thanks for info but I have tested it myself as a recipient and I accepted the invite but the reiceiver is not responding back

Comment: Are you expecting a reply to your custom domain? Inbound XMPP to App Engine does not work with custom domains.

Comment: No, I am just expecting a simple text reply in my  google chat app inside my gmail account